# Ожерелье, серьги — этимология

Tags: этимология

Браслет — это понятно, иностранное слово. Дальше: оплечье — на плечах, ошейник — на шее, перстень — на персте, а вот ожерелье и серьги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ожерелье - от "жерло", оно же - горло.
А вот серьга, кажется, заимствование, древнее.

Answer (score 1):

По Фасмеру, слово "ожерелье" происходит от праславянского, от которого в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. ***ожерелие***, укр. ***ожере́лля***, сербохорв. ***о̀ждриjелиjе*** «воротник», словенск. ***ožrȇlje*** «грудь и шея коровы, быка». Производное от ***жерело*** (ср. также горло). Ср. диал. ***ого́рлие*** «ожерелье; ошейник».

По Фасмеру, слово "серьга" происходит от неустановленной формы; наиболее вероятным считается заимствование древнерусского ***серьга*** из тюрского; Сравним с другими языками: др-чув. ****śürüɣ*** «кольцо», чув. ***śǝrǝ, śørǝ*** «кольцо», тат. ***jözök***, тур., чагат. ***jüzük*** — то же; ср. также: чагат. ***isirɣa***, ***уsуrɣа*** «ушные подвески», туркм., караим., кыпч., карач., балк., тат., казах., кирг., ойрат., тел., леб., шор., кюэр. ***syrɣa*** «серьга».